# Target "${build.target}" does not exist in the project "AppNameA"

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, build

**Error is at the bottom**

I am getting this error during the `-build-setup` task when trying to run a build.xml file (generated by the android sdk) for a project that has a couple dependencies and the task i am trying to run is `-compile`. I am using eclipse to run this ant file using the auto build function. I assigned this `build.xml` file as a builder for the project and set it as the only bulider. Then set the targets to the following:

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_AFTER_CLEAN_TARGETS" value="-compile,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_AUTO_TARGETS" value="-compile,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_CLEAN_TARGETS" value="clean,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_MANUAL_TARGETS" value="clean,nodeps,debug,"/>
```

Both the dependencies are also using the generated `build.xml` files. All of my `build.xml` files are over riding the `-compile` task. Posted at the bottom is the `-compile` task that is in the `build.xml` files.

The dependency projects are android libraries and i have their ant builder configured in eclipse as the following:

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_AFTER_CLEAN_TARGETS" value="nodeps,debug,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_AUTO_TARGETS" value="nodeps,debug,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_CLEAN_TARGETS" value="clean,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_MANUAL_TARGETS" value="debug,"/>
```

Why do i keep getting this error and how do i fix this?

---

---

**My current work around**

If i change the targets of the `AppNameA` to the following, it works fine. However, i do not want to have to do this... debug takes too long when all you really want is to compile at those points.

```
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_AFTER_CLEAN_TARGETS" value="debug,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_AUTO_TARGETS" value="debug,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_CLEAN_TARGETS" value="clean,"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.ant.ui.ATTR_ANT_MANUAL_TARGETS" value="clean,nodeps,debug,"/>
```

---

**Here is the exact error:**

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\myusername\android-sdks\tools\ant\build.xml:485: The following error occurred while executing this line:
Target "${build.target}" does not exist in the project "AppNameA".
```

---

**The `-compile` task that is in the `build.xml` files.**

(Basically the same as the original, there is one minor change...)

```
<!-- Compiles this project's .java files into .class files. -->
<target name="-compile" depends="-build-setup, -pre-build, -code-gen, -pre-compile">
    <do-only-if-manifest-hasCode elseText="hasCode = false. Skipping...">
        <!-- If android rules are used for a test project, its classpath should include
             tested project's location -->
        <condition property="extensible.classpath"
                value="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/bin/classes"
                else=".">
            <isset property="tested.project.absolute.dir" />
        </condition>
        <condition property="extensible.libs.classpath"
                value="${tested.project.absolute.dir}/${jar.libs.dir}"
                else="${jar.libs.dir}">
            <isset property="tested.project.absolute.dir" />
        </condition>
        <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
                source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
                debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
                destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
                bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
                verbose="${verbose}"
                classpath="${extensible.classpath}"
                classpathref="jar.libs.ref"
                excludes="${filesToExcludeFromCompile}"
                failonerror="true"
            >
            <src path="${source.absolute.dir}" />
            <src path="${gen.absolute.dir}" />
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="${extensible.libs.classpath}" includes="*.jar" />
            </classpath>
            <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
        </javac>
        <!-- if the project is a library then we generate a jar file -->
        <if condition="${project.is.library}">
            <then>
                <echo>Creating library output jar file...</echo>
                <property name="out.library.jar.file" location="${out.absolute.dir}/classes.jar" />
                <if>
                    <condition>
                        <length string="${android.package.excludes}" trim="true" when="greater" length="0" />
                    </condition>
                    <then>
                        <echo>Custom jar packaging exclusion: ${android.package.excludes}</echo>
                    </then>
                </if>
                <jar destfile="${out.library.jar.file}">
                    <fileset dir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}" excludes="**/R.class **/R$*.class"/>
                    <fileset dir="${source.absolute.dir}" excludes="**/*.java ${android.package.excludes}" />
                </jar>
            </then>
        </if>

        <!-- if the project is instrumented, intrument the classes -->
        <if condition="${build.is.instrumented}">
            <then>
                <echo>Instrumenting classes from ${out.absolute.dir}/classes...</echo>
                <!-- It only instruments class files, not any external libs -->
                <emma enabled="true">
                    <instr verbosity="${verbosity}"
                           mode="overwrite"
                           instrpath="${out.absolute.dir}/classes"
                           outdir="${out.absolute.dir}/classes">
                    </instr>
                    <!-- TODO: exclusion filters on R*.class and allowing custom exclusion from
                         user defined file -->
                </emma>
            </then>
        </if>
    </do-only-if-manifest-hasCode>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

`${build.target}` is actually set in the `-set-debug-mode` and `-set-release-mode` tasks. So, when calling the `-compile` task directly it is not calling either of those tasks as dependencies.

Therefor, `${build.target}` is never actually set.

A workaround for this is to override one of the tasks and have it set the `${build.target}` when it is not set. Have it set to some default you approve.

Comment: Can you give sample code and xml for how you solved this problem? Thanks

Comment: You could possibly try calling the `-set-debug-mode` target from within your custom `-compile` target. Just call it the first thing you do. But we actually scrapped this idea, and decided it was not worth the effort to try and get our external build process working in eclipse. So, i am unable to test it further.

Answer (score 0):

A property called **java.target** is unset in your build.xml file.

I reckon the message is being thrown by the following ANT task, which has an attribute called "target":

```
<javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
        source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
        debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
        destdir="${out.classes.absolute.dir}"
        bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
        verbose="${verbose}"
        classpath="${extensible.classpath}"
        classpathref="jar.libs.ref"
        excludes="${filesToExcludeFromCompile}"
        failonerror="true"
    >
```

Comment: Is that attribute asking for the target version of java? I also do not believe this to be the problem, but i will set it to what ever extra information you give me in the response to this message and give it a go. Thanks

Comment: Inside the android parent build.xml, they are setting this value already. And it is set to 1.5. It is `line 51` in the parent `build.xml` that android provides. This is still not resolved.